# Why the record is posted twice in the database?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Can you tell me, why the record is posted twice in the database. I think. this happens because I use **save()** method. But shouldn't I save the master-entity and dependent-entity separately?

```
Controller method:
@RequestMapping(value = "/addComment/{topicId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveComment(@PathVariable int topicId, @ModelAttribute("newComment")Comment comment, BindingResult result, Model model){
        Topic commentedTopic = topicService.findTopicByID(topicId);
        commentedTopic.addComment(comment);

        // TODO: Add a validator here
        if (!comment.isValid() ){
            return "//";

        }
        // Go to the "Show topic" page
        commentService.saveComment(comment);

        return "redirect:../details/" + topicService.saveTopic(commentedTopic);

}
```

Services:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CommentService {

    @Autowired
    private CommentRepository commentRepository;

    public int saveComment(Comment comment){
        return commentRepository.save(comment).getId();

    }   

}

@Service
@Transactional
public class TopicService {
    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;

    public int saveTopic(Topic topic){
        return topicRepository.save(topic).getId();

    }
}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_TOPIC")
public class Topic {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User author;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
    private Tag topicTag;

    private String name;
    private String text;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "topic", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_COMMENT")
public class Comment
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="TOPIC_ID")
    private Topic topic;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User author;

    private String text;
    private Date creationDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this concrete case, you do not need to save the master and the client.

- Saving the master or the client would be enough (with this concrete mapping)

But I think the main problem is that you do not have a good equals method in your `Comment` so your ORM Provider think that there are two different comments, and therefore store them twice.

Comment: In my case, saving the master or the client is enough